# How to do subtractions in a list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list of 25 data frames. My goal is to do a subtraction of one column from another in each list. For example:

```
a1 <- list(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[6:10,])
```

I have to calculate `drat` - `wt` and make a new column to show to results. Like this:

```
[[1]]
                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Results
Mazda RX4       21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    1.28
Mazda RX4 Wag   21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   1.025

[[2]]
              mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb Results
Valiant      18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1   -0.70
Duster 360   14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4   -0.36
```

I could not figure it out. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: `lapply(a1, function(d) { d$result <- d$drat - d$wt ; d})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a2` is a list with all the same data frame in `a1` except that one column `Results` is updated.

```
a1 <- list(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[6:10,])

a2 <- lapply(a1, function(dt){
  dt$Results <- dt$drat - dt$wt
  return(dt)})
```